# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

in my iOS app's `viewDidLoad` method, i have the following line of code:

```
loadDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1.0", "version number", nil];
```

and it causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. i don't know why. nothing else in the `viewDidLoad` method uses the object except the other side of the if/else statement this line is in, so there's no way it could have been released already. i'm just not sure what the problem is. if you want to see my whole `viewDidLoad` method, here it is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tapsBackground = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    tapsBackground.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapsBackground];

    saveChangesButton.hidden = YES;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"presets.plist"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        loadDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }

    else{
        loadDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1.0", "version number", nil];
        [loadDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message. Also, where is `loadDict` declared?

Comment: the only error message i'm getting is Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" loadDict is declared in the interface

Comment: also, thanks for editing it. i'm not very good at using stackoverflow's text editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing `@` in the second string i.e. `"version number"`.

```
loadDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1.0", "version number", nil];
```

It should be,

```
loadDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1.0", @"version number", nil];
```

Comment: yea i already figured this out. thanks though! i guess i was thinking java when writing that argument =P

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue once. Try this, it worked for me:

```
self.loadDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1.0", "version number", nil];
```

I'm assuming you have already made loadDict a property. You can use Product>Profile>allocations to pin-point the problem in such cases.

Comment: thanks. this didn't turn out to be the issue but i did have that problem later on in my program and trying this fixed it so thanks